# how to compare i-node numbers of files in C

Tags: c, file, copy

how would you be able to check if the files have the same/different i-node numbers in C? 
Because I want the rightly get the source and destination file information, where the files need to be rightly tested if they are the same. 
Code:

```
#define BUFFER 100 // ** increased - file path can get pretty long
#define buffersize     4096
#define copymode      0644

void error(char *, char *);
int file_exist(char *filename)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat (filename, &buffer) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    int ac;
    char *avc[4096];
    int     in_fd, out_fd, chars_n;
    char    buf[BUFFERSIZE];

    char ch, sourceFile[20], targetFile[20];
    FILE *source, *target;
    printf("Enter name of file to copy\n");
    fgets(source_file, 20, stdin);

    source = fopen(sourceFile, "r");
    *avc = sourceFile;
    if( source == NULL )
    {
        printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter name of target file\n");
    fgets(targetFile, 20, stdin);

    // open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mod);
    if (file_exist (targetFile))
    {
        printf("File exists. \n");
    }
    else
        target = fopen(targetFile, "w");

    int dFN;
    dFN = malloc(strlen(targetFile) + strlen(av[2] + 1));

    if( target == NULL )
    {
        fclose(source);
        printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
        fputc(ch, target);

    printf("File copied successfully.\n");

    fclose(source);
    fclose(target);



    if ( ac != 3 ){
        fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s source destination\n", *avc);
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( (in_fd=open(avc[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
        error("Cannot open ", avc[1]);

    if ( (out_fd=creat( avc[2], copymode)) == -1 )
        error( "Cannot creat", avc[2]);


    while ( (chars_n = read(in_fd , buf, buffersize)) > 0 )
        if ( write( out_fd, buf, chars_n ) != chars_n )
            error("Write error to ", av[2]);
    if ( chars_n == -1 )
        error("Read error from ", avc[1]);


    if ( close(in_fd) == -1 || close(out_fd) == -1 )
        error("Error closing files","");

    return 0;
}

void error(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s ", s1);
    perror(s2);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem? what is your question?

Comment: the above code includes the headers: #include <stdio.h>,
#include        <unistd.h>, 
#include        <fcntl.h>, and
#include <sys/stat.h>

Comment: What??? that is your problem??? :-p

Comment: I just want to copy a certain file into another file in the same directory, where I could get source and copied destination file information, using things like: malloc and stat.

Comment: you're missing the point. see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use the `stat`(2) or `fstat` function call, which returns various informations about a file, including its inode number.

See for example http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html

Comment: How would you be able to copy a file into a new file in the same directory?

Comment: Open the input- and output- files, loop over read+write, and close them.